# Android MapView not filling parent inside CardView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

Let me briefly explain what I'm trying to do. I am getting a restaurant from Yelp and putting the restaurant's attributes into a CardView. The reason I want a CardView is because I want swiping functionality. I want to be able to swipe left, right, and up. [To do this, I need a RecyclerView to handle every direction (or so I've come to understand from reading this).](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.h1v7nnqhu) If someone has a better way to do this please let me know.

For some reason, when you set MapView's `layout_height` to a concrete value, it resizes fine. But it won't fill the parent.

I don't want to set a concrete value for obvious compatibility issues.

Also, is it possible to disable swiping on the MapView part of the CardView?

So here are my layout files:

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Use Zip Code"
            android:id="@+id/useZip"
            android:checked="false" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Use Location"
            android:id="@+id/useLocation"
            android:checked="false" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/zipcode"
        android:hint="zip code"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Generate"
        android:id="@+id/generate"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/zipcode"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/generate"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/container">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**restaurant_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/restaurantContainer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_75sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_75sdp"
                    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_75sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:id="@+id/rating"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/categories"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_5sdp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/mapView"
                map:mapType="normal"
                map:liteMode="true"
                map:cameraZoom="14"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here's a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Comment: What's the size of parent? Your CardView height is `fill_parent`. You should either set some height or set it to wrap_content.

Comment: @Sharj the parent of whom? If you mean the RecyclerView, it's set to `fill_parent`. I tried setting CardView's height to `wrap_content`, no change, just like the screenshot above.

Comment: Either set CardView height to let's say 200dp and MapView to `fill_parent`. This way it will fill remaining height, you can adjust CardView height. or  set CardView height to `wrap_content` and then provide your MapView height like 200dp (or whatever height you want).

Comment: @Sharj your suggestion works, but is it impossible to have the MapView just fill the rest of the card dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set `CardView` height to let's say `200dp` and MapView to fill_parent.

This way it will fill remaining height, you can adjust `CardView` height. or set `CardView` height to wrap_content and then provide your `MapView` height like `200dp` (or whatever height you want).

Update: RecyclerView is a scroll view. Which means it has infinite height and every Card you put in it should have it's own height, card can't have `fill_parent`.

Now if you want your MapView to have rest of the height. I assume you mean rest of the Card height. For this first you have to define how long you want your Card to be.

Ex: If you set your Card height to 500dp, MapView to fill_parent and your content other than MapView inside Card is 100dp then MapView will take rest of the height (400dp).

If you want MapView to take rest of the height on the mobile screen then you have to remove RecyclerView and just use Card.

Comment: Can just a `Card` be swiped left, right, and up? This is mainly why I implemented a RecyclerView.

Comment: Maybe there's a way but I am not aware off. You can post a new question but that.